# Как прокинуть браузерное событие через кастомное?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

http://jsfiddle.net/m2dqd236/

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  $(document).trigger('click-anywhere', $.event.fix(event));
}, true);

$(document).on('click-anywhere', function (event, e) {
  console.log('>>> click-anywhere', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target, e.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent, e.originalEvent);
}).on('click', function (event) {
  console.log('>>> click', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Когда в приведённом примере нажимаем на кнопку, видим в консоли следующий вывод:

```
>>> click-anywhere [p.Event, p.Event]
target #document <button>​Click me​</button>​
originalEvent undefined MouseEvent {}
>>> click [p.Event]
target <button>​Click me​</button>​
originalEvent MouseEvent {}
```

Как сделать, чтобы для кастомного события `click-anywhere` обработчику первым аргументом передавалось нормальное событие, которое в текущей реализации передаётся вторым?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045147/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33045147/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Детально с реализацией событий в jQuery не знаком, но судя по документации `.trigger()` первым аргументом может принимать объект события. Преобразовав оригинальное событие в jQuery событие, можно поменять его тип на кастомный и собственно затригерить:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var jqEvent = $.event.fix(event);
    jqEvent.type = 'click-anywhere';
    $(document).trigger(jqEvent);
}, true);
```

Получившееся событие будет иметь параметры оригинального события, разве что тип будет отличаться. Тем не менее оригинальное событие все равно будет доступно через `jqEvent.originalEvent`.

[Измененный jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nopb994q/).

Заметка: теоретически последствий такого вызова с изменением типа быть не должно, но точно не уверен + будет зависеть от того, как планируется использовать событие.

Comment: Думаю, это мне и надо. На вид кажется лучше, чем способ с браузерным dispatchEvent (особенно в плане фоллбека для IE8). Конечно, если побочных эффектов не будет.

Comment: Вероятно, фоллбек будет выглядеть примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/nopb994q/1/

Comment: Только в этом варианте нужно быть осторожным со вторым `event.type = type;`, т.к. значение меняется по ссылке. Даже в консоли видно, что во время выполнения обработчика тип евена - `click-anywhere`, а после - `click`. И мне если честно не очень понятно, зачем менять тип обратно.

Comment: А, все, разобрался -  чтобы не менять событие для последующих обработчиков `click`... Магия, да и только. Здесь тогда будет иметь значение порядок создания обработчиков.

Comment: Один обработчик не может быть внутри другого, поэтому портиться вроде ничего не должно. По идее, надо бы ещё `return` приделать, но в моём случае он не особо нужен. Да и вообще, отменять событие на document, когда оно может быть в стадии capturing, а может в bubbling (IE8) до добра вряд ли доведёт, так что не буду.

Comment: Кстати, то, что этот обработчик будет висеть первым, я обеспечу.

Answer (score 0):

[Вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045786/4928642) от @PrestonS на английском SO:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click-anywhere', event));
}, true);

$(document).on('click-anywhere', function (event) {
  console.log('>>> click-anywhere', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent);
}).on('click', function (event) {
  console.log('>>> click', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
```